# Metro Tiles individually resize

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, microsoft-metro, datatemplate

Hey all I am having a hard time trying to find the setting (if there even is one) in order to size each metro tile individually from each other. Currently it changes every tile no matter which one you choose to resize.

This is the tiles normally:

[image]

And this is the tiles resizing (I am resizing the first top tile):

[image]

I have not yet found any settings in the properties for this but then again I could be overlooking it.

It would be great to let me know how I can go about fixing this :)

**update**

[image]

Comment: What is the type of your project? Is it a UWP app?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT it looks to be a Windows 8 grid app

Comment: May I know why do you want to resize each tile individually in xaml designer? In addition, the reason why it changes every tile no matter which one you choose to resize is because the size of each tile is determined by the size of the first one. If you want to have different sized tiles, you could override the ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride method to create a custom panel for the GridView's ItemPanel or create different DataTemplate for the GridView.